# Page 404 in IIS 7.5 with Intergrated Pipeline, fine with Classic pipeline

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, iis-7.5, sitecore

I'm running sitecore 6.4 under IIS 7.5 and I'm having a problem with the following URL:
http://www.thegreensheet.com/Classifieds/MERCHANDISE/Animals%20Pets%20and%20More.aspx?Id=3191212&city=Houston

Basically the layout renders normaly when IIS is in classic mode, but if I change it to intergrated I get an IIS 404 page.  The really weird thing is that it works in both classic and intergrated if browsing from the local server itself.  All our other items/layouts work fine in IIS 7.5 when under Intergrated Mode.  All the handlers under httpHandlers and handlers tags are there...  I'm really at a loss...

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the page was, in error, setting the response status code to 404.  Under classic mode IIS would render out the contents of the page and set the status to 404.  Under integrated mode it would set the status code to 404, but render out the IIS 404 page. I found it by reviewing the IIS logs and using firefox to watch the response codes in real time.  Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.
-James

Comment: You haven't wasted anyone's time. You found a solution and posted it for the benefit of others. The next person who has the same problem will know how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, and indeed this is not wasting time.

Answer (score 1):

If you add this

```
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

before setting the

```
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
```

Then Sitecore will be able to handle the error and still return a 404 Status Code.

This is because Windows 2008 server is running IIS 7.5 which will by default override the HTTP response with its default error pages if the page returns a HTTP error status code such as 404 or 500.